# Android MediaStore - store zip file and open as File

Tags: android, file, mediastore

Good Morning,

I have a problem with MediaStore on Android 11. I have to download .zip file, then open it and get file uri and path.

This is code for saving file and works correctly. I can find the file.

```
 if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.Q) {
            imageCollection = MediaStore.Files.getContentUri(MediaStore.VOLUME_EXTERNAL_PRIMARY);

            ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
            contentValues.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.DISPLAY_NAME, fileName);
            contentValues.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.MIME_TYPE, "application/zip");
            contentValues.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.SIZE, lengthOfFile);
            
            Uri uri = context.getContentResolver().insert(MediaStore.Files.getContentUri("external"), contentValues);
            OutputStream outputStream = context.getContentResolver().openOutputStream(uri);

            InputStream input = new BufferedInputStream(url.openStream(), 8192);
            byte data[] = new byte[1024];
            long total = 0;
            while ((count = input.read(data)) != -1) {
                total += count;
                publishProgress("" + (int) ((total * 100) / lengthOfFile));
                outputStream.write(data, 0, count);
            }

            outputStream.flush();
            outputStream.close();
            input.close();
 }
```

But I cannot open this file later.

```
                 val collection = if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.Q) {
                                MediaStore.Files.getContentUri("external")
                            } else {
                                MediaStore.Video.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI
                            }

                    val projection = arrayOf(
                            MediaStore.Files.FileColumns.RELATIVE_PATH,
                            MediaStore.Files.FileColumns.DISPLAY_NAME,
                            MediaStore.Files.FileColumns.SIZE,
                            MediaStore.Files.FileColumns._ID
                    )


                    val cursor = requireContext().contentResolver.query(collection, projection, null, null, null)


                    if (cursor!!.getCount() == 0) {
                        Log.d(TAG, "No file")
                    } else {
                        val idColumn=cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Files.FileColumns._ID)
                        val nameColumn = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.MediaColumns.DISPLAY_NAME)
                        val pathColumn = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.MediaColumns.RELATIVE_PATH)


                        while (cursor!!.moveToNext()) {
                            val id = cursor.getLong(idColumn)
                            val name = cursor.getString(nameColumn)
                            val path = cursor.getString(pathColumn)


                            if (name == "2.1.2.zip") {

                                val contentUri: Uri =  MediaStore.Files.getContentUri("external")
                                
                             
                                val file= File("content://media/external/file/2.1.2.zip")
                                if (file.exists()) {
                                    Log.d(TAG, "File not exist")
                                } else {
                                    Log.d(TAG, "Error")
                                }
```

path value return: Download/

name value return: 2.1.2.zip

MediaStore.Files.getContentUri("external"): content://media/external/file

Have any one idea how get access to this file? I try a lot of different way to get file but always get "File not exist".

Comment: `"content://media/external/file/2.1.2.zip"` We cannot see where you got this content scheme from. And why you hard coded it. But it looks ok. It should be the same content scheme you obtained from insert(). Please confirm.

Comment: Of course you cannot use the File class for such a content scheme uri.

Comment: Further you should tell if your own app will handle the zip file or that you wanna start another app to to somerhing with it.

Comment: I have hardcoded for example. I will use zip in my on app

Comment: You did not answer all my questions/remarks. I can only stop now.

Comment: I found solution how get file path but i used deprected attribute:
`cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.MediaColumns.DATA)
 
val data = cursor.getString(dataColumn)`
and in data i have path to file but how use `ContentResolver#openFileDescriptor(Uri, String)` to getting file path?